# Cordova Application using OAuth.io plugin Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, visual-studio-2013

using Visual Studio Multi-Device Hybrid Apps with cordova

added     https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-phonegap to config XML, seems to be pulling in the SDK, problem happens when using

```
  OAuth.popup('google')
   .done(function (result) {         <------------Done is Undefined
      callback(null, result);
  })
```

I get Exception: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined, strange the Oauth object exists so references and so on should be ok, any ideas ???

[image]

***********UPDATE***********************************

If I do this and remove .done

```
  OAuth.popup('facebook', function (error, result) {
   if (error) {
      alert(error); // do something with error
       return;
    }

   alert(result.access_token); // do something with result
   });
```

It kind of runs the popup weird ...

[image]

I've followed the code all the way to the inAppBrowser runs the popup. no errors noting, just the windows does not open properly, if i throw the URL in the browser i can see it attempting to do oauth stuff, hmmmm

****Update 2 have dropped in email to support as want to use in a product or two, let's hope support can figure it out.*******************************************************

**************Update 3 ***********************************************************
So i tested on a nexus 7 with ADB drivers, and it works hurray, but it should work in the ripple emulator too, I know there are thread saying the inAppBrowser does not work in Ripple but I have to question that as you can see in this video it does work
See this video by MS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b8nWMs38Ig (skip to 25mins) and look so why not ???

Comment: Have you **Whilelisted** the URLs(yahoo,facebook...etc) as per the documentation.

Comment: yes i believe so  <access origin="*" />

Comment: Did you initialize the OAuth object with a OAuth.io app public key?

OAuth.initialize('your_app_public_key');

This problem usually occurs when that's not done.

Comment: yes , just above   OAuth.initialize('xyzqwerty123')